# Python nested for-loops & break statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, range

I'm working my way through an official Python tutorial and I can't for the life of me figure out how the nested for loops work in example [4.4](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            print n, '==', x, '*', n/x
            break
    else:
        # loop fell through w/o finding a factor
        print n, 'is a prime number'
```

`range(2, 10)` produces:`n = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
,so the way I understand it the inner for loop: `for x in range(2, n):`
should produce `(x, n-1)` and thus the following pairs of `x, n` with each iteration:
`(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (5, 4), (6, 5), (7, 6), (8, 7), (9, 8)`.
Now, obviously that would never produce `n % x == 0` but that's the only way I can think about it. 
When I print this piece of code:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
    for x in range(2, n):
        print x, n
```

to check what numbers will be generated, it returns (the first 6 pairs):

```
2 3
2 4
3 4
2 5
3 5
4 5
```

How can the first pair `x, n` be `2, 3` if the first `n` is `2 - 1` since the last position of `range()` will be excluded. I'm utterly and miserably lost.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `range(x,x)` returns an empty list. In the first iteration you call `for x in range(2, n)` with `n=2`. This loop is completely skipped and Python continues with the next iteration of the outer-loop.

Comment: that makes sense, but if at the first iteration when the loop is not skipped the `n = 3` how is the first line of output possible (the line the says `2 is a prime number`?).

Answer (score 0):

Using the second code snippet for example:

```
for n in range(2, 10):
```

`n` doesn't start from `2 - 1`, it starts with `2`, then `3`, `4`, until `9`.

In the nested loop:

```
    for x in range(2, n):
```

When `n` is `2`, `for x in range(2, 2)` is an empty range. When `n` is `3`, `x` could be `2`, generating the first valid pair `2 3`. When `n` is `4`, `x` could be `2` and `3`, generating the second the third pair `2 4` and `3 4`. The rest is similar.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.
`for x in range(2, n)` if `n` happens to be, say `7` it'd be: `n = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` thus when `n = 2` it'd be in fact `1`, since the last value is never included, no?